What is monopole, mathematically?
$\newcommand{\realset}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\lapop}[1]{\nabla^{2} #1}$
$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert}$
$\newcommand{\shift}[1]{\tau_{#1}}$
Recently, I wrote down the following theorem in my optics R&D document: Let $\boldsymbol{s} \in \realset^{3}$ and $f$ be a function such that for any $\boldsymbol{x} \in \realset^{3} \setminus \left\{\boldsymbol{s}\right\}$,
\begin{equation*}
f\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right) = \frac{e^{i k \norm{\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{s}}}}{4 \pi \norm{\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{s}}}.
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
\lapop f + k^{2} f = - \shift{\boldsymbol{s}} \delta.
\end{equation*}
After some thinking, I became confused. It is clear that $\delta$ is a tempered distribution. Then this $f\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right) = \frac{e^{i k \norm{\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{s}}}}{4 \pi \norm{\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{s}}}$ must also be related to tempered distribution. It seems to me that this $f$ is not a Schwartz function, so that it is not in the dual space of the Schwartz space. Then I am thinking, can we define a tempered distribution $T$ such that for any Schwartz function $\varphi$, $T \varphi = \int_{\realset^{3}} f \varphi$? But $f$ has a singularity. How can we define the tempered distribution so that it aligns beautifully with theory of Fourier analysis? Can we allow improper integral to appear in definition of tempered distributions?

Let me set $s=0$ because I don’t feel like typing it all out (and you should verify this is no loss of generality).
The function $f(x)=\frac{e^{ik\|x\|}}{4\pi\|x\|}$ defined on $\Bbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$ does indeed have a (pointwise) singularity at the origin. But, it is an integrable singularity; think of $\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\,dr$. In fact, our situation is strictly better:
\begin{align}
\int_{B_R(0)}|f(x)|\,dx&=\int_0^R\frac{1}{4\pi r}\cdot 4\pi r^2,dr=\frac{R^2}{2}<\infty.
\end{align}
So, the function $f$ is locally integrable. It is a standard fact that every locally integrable function can be treated as a distribution, i.e there is a canonical injection $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Bbb{R}^n)\hookrightarrow \mathcal{D}’(\Bbb{R}^n)$. So, we can consider the distribution $T_f\in\mathcal{D}’(\Bbb{R}^3)$, and we can compute the Helmholtz operator $\Delta T_f+k^2T_f$ in the distributional sense, and you can check you get a Dirac delta.
To determine whether or not a locally integrable function actually gives rise to a tempered distribution, we have to check that the function doesn’t grow too rapidly at infinity. In general, if the function grows at most polynomially, then it will give rise to a tempered distribution (because when you multiply by Schwartz function and integrate, the Schwartz function can ‘eat up’/‘compensate’ for the polynomial growth). In our case, the function $f$ actually decays at infinity. Hence, $f$ does define a tempered distribution $T_{f}\in \mathcal{S}’(\Bbb{R}^3)$ via integration $\phi\mapsto\int_{\Bbb{R}^3}f\phi$. Now that you have a tempered distribution, you can actually go ahead and try solving the inhomogeneous Helmholtz’s equation on $\Bbb{R}^3$ using Fourier transforms or whatnot.

I guess you are using the following integral: $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\mathrm{R}^{3} \setminus ball\left{\boldsymbol{0}, \epsilon\right}} f\varphi $ to define the tempered distribution from $f$.

@ZiqiFan you could, but you don’t need to. The Lebesgue integral handles this perfectly well. Having a function not be defined at one point is irrelevant. The function $f\phi$ is a.e defined, it is measurable, and $|f\phi|$ has a finite integral, i.e $f\phi\in L^1(\Bbb{R}^3)$, so I can literally write down $\int_{\Bbb{R}^3}f\phi$, and it makes sense (and I can then prove that this equals the $\epsilon$ limit you wrote down, as a trivial application of Lebesgue’s dominated convergence theorem).
